# How to change permissions of a file in Linux with C++

Tags: c++, linux, permissions, system-calls

I want to change the permissions of a file with C++ in Linux. The user has to enter the permissions using this syntax: "Please enter the permissions: rwx-w-r--" in the terminal.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: [chmod(2) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html)

Comment: How can I use the syntax rwx------ with chmod??

Comment: Parse it yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() { 
  chmod("./myfile", S_IRWXU); // enables owner to rwx file
}
```

See `man 2 chmod` for more details.

If the question is how to parse a 9 character string of the form "rwx-w-r--", realize that the permissions are encoded in an int as bits. If a bit is on, that permission is on. The following code will take your string, turn it into bits, in the obvious way...no validation etc. is done. It's a proof-of-concept.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int parse(char* perms) {
  int bits = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
    if (perms[i] != '-') {
      bits |= 1<<(8-i);
    }
  }
  return bits;
}
int main() { 
  char perms[]="rwx-w-r--";
  int exmp = S_IRWXU | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH;
  printf("%d %d\n", parse(perms), exmp);
  // outputs 468 468
}
```